# Can't force List<int> to be required

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to use Data Annotations to add validation to a List in my model that cannot be empty. I've tried several implementations of a custom attribute, including ones [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428907/required-attribute-on-generic-list-property) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146732/viewmodel-validation-for-a-list).

My view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @* Model has a list of ints, LocationIDs *@
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LocationIDs, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select class="select2 form-control" multiple id="LocationIDs" name="LocationIDs">
            @* Adds every possible option to select box *@
            @foreach (LocationModel loc in db.Locations)
            {
                <option value="@loc.ID">@loc.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LocationIDs, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Model:

```
public class ClientModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required] // Does nothing
    public List<int> LocationIDs { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,LocationIDs")] ClientModel clientModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Clients.Add(clientModel);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(clientModel);
}
```

One of the (functionally identical) attributes I've tried:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public sealed class CannotBeEmptyAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var list = value as IEnumerable;
        return list != null && list.GetEnumerator().MoveNext();
    }
}
```

Currently, checking for a null or empty list passes validation, even if nothing is chosen. In this case, a list of length one, containing the first option, is bound.

---

I've confirmed that the controller is actually sent a `List` of length one. I'm not sure how to change this behavior, however. I still think this may be what was described in the below block quote.

---

I ***think*** my problem may be described in [this answer's edit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6429119/), but I'm not sure how to solve it.

Excerpt below:

> You'll also have to be careful how you bind your list in your view.
>   For example, if you bind a List to a view like this:

```
<input name="ListName[0]" type="text" />
<input name="ListName[1]" type="text" />
<input name="ListName[2]" type="text" />
<input name="ListName[3]" type="text" />
<input name="ListName[4]" type="text" />
```

> The MVC model binder will always put 5 elements in your
>   list, all String.Empty. If this is how your View works, your attribute
>   would need to get a bit more complex, such as using Reflection to pull
>   the generic type parameter and comparing each list element with
>   default(T) or something.

Comment: Are you trying to validate that the end-user has selected an item in `select`, or are you trying to validate that `model.LocationIDs` has entries in it, or both?

Comment: Both, I suppose. Client-side would be the `select`, server-side would be `model.LocationIDs`. I don't have a 100% thorough understanding of the automagic validation properties, but I do know that data annotations prevents invalid values from being saved (essential) while also providing an error message to the end user.

Comment: @mjwills How could I edit my question to make that more clear?

Comment: I suspect `ValidationMessageFor` may help you for the former (selected an item) but not the latter (has entries in it).

Comment: @mjwills `ValidationMessageFor` is just a placeholder for the error message, which gets displayed if validation fails.

Comment: You have not shown your model or the validation attributes applies to its properties. A you have not even ahown a view that binds a form control to a property (your manual `<select>` does not do any validation). How in the world do you expect anyone to understand this

Comment: @StephenMuecke I guess I take some things for granted. Does the edit help?

Comment: But I did show my model property and the attributes I've applied.

Comment: You showed the POST endpoint. I suspect he wants to see the GET endpoint.

Comment: You have not marked the property `public` so it will not bind to anything. And your view code majes no sense. You need to use `ListBoxFor()` to corectly bind and use clunt side validation.

Comment: @Stephen That's simply not true. And you're right, I did forget the public initially. As far as I can tell, it goes off of the `name`/`id` HTML attributes. I have other validation working with a nearly identical selectbox.

Comment: What is not true? And you cannot possibly get client side validation because your not generating any `data-val` attributes used by `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` to add the rules to `jquery.validate`. And of course your code will never give you true 2-way model binding either

Comment: @Stephen It's not true that binding doesn't happen. Like I said, those helper methods aren't magic (at least outside of client-side validation), they just set the `name` and `id` to match what you want to bind to. Some `data-val` attributes are generated by `ValidationMessageFor` -- by what you're saying, I presume they're not the ones I need. I think I said client-side when I should not have -- the message is displayed, but only after a trip to the server. So, validated client-side, but the error is correctly displayed when applicable.

Comment: Is it possible that some (all?) custom validation attributes aren't supported by client-side validation? My phone number validation element looks like [this](https://i.imgur.com/JgYDCnX.png), using the built-in regex attribute. But I don't see how those `data` attributes could possibly support every type of validation.

Comment: If that's is what you believe then you have an enormous amount to learn! (1) The `HtmlHelper` methods use `ViewData`, the `ModelState` and finally the property value for binding in that order. (2) `ValidationMessageFor()` does not generate any `data-val` attributes (its just a placeholder) - they are generated by the the `EditorFor()`, `TextboxFor`, `DropDownListFor()` etc methods. (3) If the value `LocationIDs` has an initial value(s) - i.e. your editing existing data, they will not be selected when the page is first rendered.

Comment: And if you want to understand valdation, then I suggest you start with [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: @Stephen I *do* have an enormous amount to learn! Teaching yourself is a slow process. But there's no way the HtmlHelpers do any magic outside of client-side validation. You can [see for yourself](https://i.imgur.com/zkzVuPJ.png), the `name` and `id` attributes are used by the form to have the server sort it out. And to be fair, I didn't say `ValidationMessageFor` generates [*useful* `data-val` attributes](https://i.imgur.com/Bu7TcXy.png). I'm well aware of (3) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could get a zero-selection to actually bind as `null` was by using `Html.ListBoxFor` (which I couldn't figure out initially – it should have been done this way from the start):

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedLocations, Model.AllLocations, new { @class = "select2 form-control" })
```

I haven't gotten client-side validation to work, but I'll post that as another question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try contructing the validator with a Type and verifying if any of the itens on the list is different of the default value of your type.
Changing the example you mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428907/required-attribute-on-generic-list-property/6429119#6429119):

```
public class CannotBeEmptyAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private const string defaultError = "'{0}' must have at least one element.";

    public Type ListType { get; private set; }

    protected CannotBeEmptyAttribute(Type listType) : base(defaultError)
    {
        this.ListType = listType;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        object defaultValue = ListType.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(ListType) : null;

        IEnumerable list = value as IEnumerable;

        if (list != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                if(item != defaultValue)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;            
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return String.Format(this.ErrorMessageString, name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `CannotBeEmptyAttribute` is fine. I've used the exact same code and it works perfectly. Make sure you change your view model to use it as well (instead of the `Required` which doesn't do what you want it to in this case.

Your custom attribute won't provide you with client-side validation unless you implement it. This means that the form will get posted even though it's invalid but `if (ModelState.IsValid)` will catch it. Have you used a debugger to see if is `IsValid` is `false`?

"Manually" creating the input is completely fine for server-side validation but client-side won't work because the necessary `data-` attributes are missing.

Here's a minimal version of a form with manually created multi-select input that works with the `CannotBeEmptyAttribute`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TestPost", "Home"))
{
    <select multiple="multiple" name="TestList">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
    @Html.ValidationMessage("TestList")
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
}
```

Comment: I just don't see any way of creating the selectbox I want without doing it manually -- other than extending `HtmlHelper`, but my explorations through the source code have not helped me create anything more advanced than `Html.SimpleText("words")` where `"words"` is built into a string somewhere and returned.

Comment: No, still no idea why. It *does* work for some seeded values, though, where I've actually set the `List` to `null` myself in the database initializer. `IsValid` is true when I send the form myself. I don't know how to check what value is being sent to the controller, though.

Comment: All I can think is that it's actually sending a list containing the first item (that's what eventually gets saved). But I don't know how to solve that. Choosing one item is intended to be valid.

Comment: I've confirmed that the controller is actually sent a `List` of length one. I'm not sure how to change this behavior, however. I still think this may be what was described in the above block quote.

Answer (score 1):

Also assigning a `MinLength` worked for me:

```
[Required, MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "Atleast one LocationId must be added")]
public List<int> LocationIDs { get; set; }
```

Comment: This only works with Array not List.