# ListBoxFor not showing ValidationMessageFor if no items are selected

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a listboxfor as shown below:

```
 @Html.Label("Members", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label required", @multiple = "multiple" })
 @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Members, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Members, new { @class = "form-control", @multiple = "multiple" })                                               
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Members, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

The problem that I am experiencing is that it does not show the validation message even if no member has been selected.

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a member")]
    public List<int> Members { get; set; }
```

Comment: Will you give a try with `public int[] Members { get; set; }` instead of `public List<int> Members { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check `RequiredAttribute` in [reference source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/RequiredAttribute.cs), you will see overriden `IsValid` method like this:

```csharp
public override bool IsValid(object value) 
{
    // checks if the object has null value
    if (value == null) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    // other stuff

    return true;
}
```

The problem here is `IsValid` method only checks for null values & null objects, but does not check `Count` property which exists in collection objects e.g. `IEnumerable<T>`. If you want to check against zero-valued `Count` property (which indicates no selected items), you need to create custom annotation attribute inherited from `RequiredAttribute` containing [`IEnumerator.MoveNext()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext?view=netframework-4.7.2) check and apply it to `List<T>` property:

```csharp
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public sealed class RequiredListAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var list = value as IEnumerable;

        // check against both null and available items inside the list
        return list != null && list.GetEnumerator().MoveNext();
    }
}

// Viewmodel implementation
public class ViewModel
{
    [RequiredList(ErrorMessage = "Please select a member")]
    public List<int> Members { get; set; }
}
```

**Note:**

Using `int[]` array type instead of `List<int>` e.g. `public int[] Members { get; set; }` should work for standard `RequiredAttribute` because array property returns `null` when no items are selected, while `List<T>` properties call default constructor which will create an empty list.

Related issue:

[Required Attribute on Generic List Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428907/required-attribute-on-generic-list-property)