# I have a Multiselect list on ASP.net Core and validaton is not woking

Tags: entity-framework, validation, asp.net-core, multi-select, tag-helpers

I have a select field

```
<select asp-for="UserCitizenships" asp-items="Model.CitizenshipsList" class="select2 required">
```

that is populated by a multiselect list

```
public MultiSelectList CitizenshipsList { get; set; }
```

And returns a List of Int

```
 public List<int> UserCitizenships
```

that I handle manually in the backend. Validation from Data Annotations is not working. I need at least one property to be populated when the form submits. Any ideas?

```
  [Required(ErrorMessage = Helpers.ErrorMessages.Required)]
    public List<int> UserCitizenships
    {
        get
        {
           ....
```

Comment: Hi, follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6429119/6797509

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have thought the following would work

```
[Required, MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "At least one item required")]
public List<int> UserCitizenships { get; set; }
```

Alternatively you could create a custom data annotation or use class level validation

```
public class YourClass : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    List<int> UserCitizenships

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (UserCitizenships.Count < 1)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult(
                $"At least one UserCitizenship should be specified.",
                new[] { nameof(UserCitizenships) });
        }
    }   
}
```